# How to do a simple pull with gitlab-ci.yml from local machine?

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

i want to write gitlab ci.yml file  to pull csv file from my local machine to gitlab repo these files changes everyday thats why i need to use ci pipline to pull new file to my repo
can anyone help

Comment: Unless your local machine is a server, e.g. supporting ssh or some other remote access protocol, there’s no way to do this. You could set up a cron job on your local machine to push regularly. Or you could just use git normally as you work. It’s very common for developers to commit and push many times per day. Setting up automated git pushes kind of defeats the purpose of explicit version control.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create NFS (Network File System) or something like WebDAV near your GitLab. Send there your file and run the pipeline after the update. Via pipeline, you can download files or read them.